# Is there a way to access OS X location services from the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, geolocation

I'd like to be able to fetch OS X's current estimate of location from the the command-line so that I can script based on it. Is there a tool that does this?

I've found apps like locations that let you trigger actions based on location but I haven't found anything that let's you fetch the actual location data.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for this, too, and failed to find one... So, I wrote one!

It's pretty simple at the moment, but it seems to basically work.  I called it [get-location](https://github.com/lindes/get-location), and you can get it from github (follow the link, above).

For the moment, I just print out the ***second*** location I receive from the service (I skip the first one, since it can be cached and old – in a future version, perhaps this will be configurable, or it's an easy hack (change the `hits` check to be `> 0`, instead of `> 1`) in the code, if you don't want to wait for that (I may or may not change it soon).

Anyway, it then prints out the results, like so (note: location data here has been changed to something made up):

```
$ ./get-location
Final location: <+12.34567890, +12.34567890> +/- 176.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2012-04-10 13:57:53 +0200
```

Another TODO item is to add other formats, and/or let you specify your own. I may add this soon, or I may add it later.  Or: Send me a pull request.  :)  (Feature requests and bug reports also welcome, preferably via the github system.  Also, check the README on github to see what I've already thought of.)

I hope you (and others) find this helpful.

***EDIT***: Now with command-line options and a few different output formats.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I haven't gotten it to work...  But http://code.google.com/p/corelocationcli/
might solve your issue....

This also seems to be a more stable package? http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/locateme/

(The issue I am having with both, might be because I am trying these on Mountain Lion....  )

While not built-ins, they both appear to use CoreLocation services....

Comment: Both solutions seem to be broken on Mountain Lion. Did you manage to get it working somehow, or found something else working on OS X 10.8? I’m sure I am not the only one interested in this ... thanks!

Comment: I really haven't messed with it at this time.  While being neat, I was really looking for a Find My iPhone type of code for portables.

Comment: Thank you, I'm the author of CoreLocationCLI and just noting that it is moved to https://github.com/fulldecent/corelocationcli and has minor improvements since then

Comment: LocateMe works for me on OS X El Capitan (10.11.6). Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
lynx -dump http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/?QRY=$1|sed -nr s/'^.*My IP address city: (.+)$/\1/p'
```

require lynx

[source](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1205/find-geographical-location-of-an-ip-address)

Comment: Nota bene: This is not the same thing.  Potentially useful, but not the same thing.  In particular, this requires having full internet access, whereas CoreServices I _believe_ can run without that, as long as wifi is enabled.  And anyway, even if I'm wrong about that, it uses WIFI-based location finding (and anything else CoreLocation might use, now or in the future), rather than just IP address, which is potentially much more accurate.  (See, e.g., [here](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/xps.php).)